# I need a query in postgres that returns the length of arrays but without taking empty values into consideration

Tags: sql, postgresql

so given the table:

```
id     | names
===============
1        {John, , Wayne}
2        {Luke, Harold, }
3        {Bill}
4        {Will, , }
```

They don't have a standard and some values may come empty ( for example {Will, , }).
I tried:

```
SELECT array_length(names, 1)
FROM nameTable
```

But I get this:

```
names
======
3
3
1
3
```

and I want it to return:

```
names
======
2
2
1
1
```

So I need something which gives me the length only of the populated fields (empty spaces like ' ') shouldn't be counted.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Postgresql .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `NULL` values and then count:

```
array_length(array_remove(names, NULL), 1)
```

For one-dimensional arrays, I find that `cardinality()` is convenient:

```
cardinality(array_remove(names, NULL))
```

Comment: This is it. it works! But instead of Null I put ' '. Thank you!

Comment: @SlimKode . . . I assumed the unseen value was `NULL`, but you can put in any value.